# Datagrid column header click and drag-and-drop

Tags: silverlight, datagrid, drag-and-drop, click, columnheader

I want to be able to run a command when a datagrid column header is clicked. The classic way is to set column header style with a button. But doing it so causes loosing ability to reorder columns.

Using `MouseLeftButtonUp` event for click does not work because the mouse is captured in the header.

How can I manage to support both click and drag-and-drop events in Silverlight's datagrid column header?

Comment: I'm trying to do this same thing.  Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: I don't need it anymore but I would try to derive own column header that would be able to somehow handle this requirement.

Comment: I ended up making my own footer and putting the click event on that.  Thanks for responding